# SQLite functions at android apps

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite

I'm very new at programming. I want to make an app where,
1. User1 will make an order (log in as user_profile_1)
2. User2 will work with that order (log in as user_profile_2)
One user shouldn't have access to other's  data.

Will SQLite allow me to do that? Seems, database must not run on user's device. And database will always get new records, so we need to update it all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, you have to create a server to store data, I think you should do these things:

1. Use PHP, NodeJS or some languages server like this to create APIs.
2. Use a MySQL database or some other database to store data on your server.
   Then, different users can log in on their device and you will call your APIs to show what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a SQLite database, the db will be local in the device. The records in the database do not share with other devices.

If you want to access the database from different devices the database will need to exist in a remote server.

You can do differents things:

- You can use a database MySql in a remote server with allowed remote access.
- You can create a rest api in a LAMP server. You can do this for example with PHP and MySql. You create a GET/POST web page, them pass the data, and the php save the information in the database. You can get the information from the database in the same way, but you should ask to the db in a periodicly time